# Internal Android Crash in Xamarin around SetSpan

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

We have a Xamarin Android app that is at times experiencing the following crash:

```
d Java.Lang.RuntimeExceptionsetSpan (13 ... 31) ends beyond length 18
Raw

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (13 ... 31) ends beyond length 18
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
    at android.widget.TextView.setSpan_internal(TextView.java:8753)
    at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.onItemClick(Editor.java:2789)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After some investigation, we have determined what causes this crash, and how others (using plain Android, not Xamarin, have solved it):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82788

The solution is to extend EditText and override two protected methods:

```
protected void setSpan_internal(Object span, int start, int end, int flags) {
    final int textLength = getText().length();
    ((Editable) getText()).setSpan(span, start, Math.min(end, textLength),  flags);
}

protected void setCursorPosition_internal(int start, int end) {
    final int textLength = getText().length();
    Selection.setSelection(((Editable) getText()), Math.min(start, textLength), Math.min(end, textLength));
}
```

Great, a simple solution. Except, of course, that Xamarin appears to make these methods private when wrapping them. They are not accessible within the Xamarin implementation of EditText (or TextView).

So does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem within Xamarin? I believe I can create a custom Android dll that performs this fix and then wrap it in Xamarin bindings. But I am hoping someone else has a simpler idea.

Comment: Reflection could probably solve this. But either way not a great solution.

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce this? I am using `InputFilterLengthFilter` and have not seen this error before using `textAutoComplete`, the words from the dictionary that are longer than the filter length get truncated...

Comment: We've only been able to reproduce it on 4.4.2, and on a particular Zebra device. But the way we reproduce it is to simply take any EditText, put some text into it, hit space, put some more text, hit space. Select the second set of letters and choose one of the spelling corrections. The app will then crash, every single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did end up creating a custom Android library that has a custom class that extends EditText and fixes the two methods (the solution mentioned in the original question).

Then I wrapped this in a Xamarin binding and it resolved the issue.

I can also confirm that this only happens on Zebra TC70 devices running 4.4.2. Very specific and obscure.

Comment: Hi @Jared. I have the same problem on a Zebra TC25. Can you post your solution?

Comment: Are you having this problem in Android or in Xamarin Android? If just regular Android, the solution is pretty simple. See here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36944935#comment5

If you are using Xamarin Android, you need to implement that solution in an Android library and then wrap it in a Xamarin custom binding. If you are not familiar with either of those concepts it will take some research. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/